# Bing Local Business Search API | Sending a request with Postman

Tags: postman, bing-api

I am trying to send a request to the Bing Local Business Search API using Postman.

It's giving a 404 status.

If I use the default URL not the regional one that matches my key it will return invalid key which makes sense, sounds like it's connecting properly.

But if I use the regional southcentral endpoint from my dashboard it returns a 404.

I signed up for the free plan and generated a key that I am using.

Here are my settings in postman. Thanks in advance.

[image: bing api postman]

Comment: Did you try removing the Content-Type: application/json?

Comment: Thanks for the quick post. I tested removing the content-type, but it's still showing a 404. I'm going to test out my key with their search api, maybe it's an issue with local business search api being new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to go into the Azure Portal. Under Cognitive Services create a new service with Bing Search v7 under the free tier. It should give you a global location. After it's created you'll get your keys. At least that worked for me. Their initial "Welcome page" keys did not work for me either, I don't understand why.

[image]

Then you'll be able to call - [https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/localbusinesses/search?q=chicago+restaurants&mkt=en-US](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/localbusinesses/search?q=%3Cwhatever%3E&mkt=en-US)

Comment: Also note I created another Cognitive service with the same settings but under the standard fee and was getting a 404. YMMV

Comment: Wow, thanks for providing this info. It is working now. Maybe they haven't updated their documentation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to URL encode the search params, the space after q=chicago should be %20.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick post. I tried adding %20 for the space and the response is still a 404. I'm starting to think it might be an issue with the endpoint.